Was Mandodari born from a frog?
That is what Sadhguru says in this video.
https://www.youtube.com/shorts/9_MyPCuQf4o
EDIT:
This is not a general inquiry about the birth of Mandodari.  It is asking for scriptural backing for one particular version put forth by Sadhguru.

Please check this https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12278/what-is-the-story-of-the-birth-of-mandodari

This question is similar to: What is the story of the birth of Mandodari?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
